Why std::is_invocable_r_v doesn't work with void return type as expected?
In the code below (demo) I can distinguish two function types in case I use in std::is_invocable_r_v the return type other than void (for example, float).
And it doesn't work with void:
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

void process(auto fn) {
    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_r_v<float, decltype(fn)>) {
        std::cout << "float function call (works just fine!)" << std::endl;
        [[maybe_unused]] auto res = fn();
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "void function call" << std::endl;
        fn();
    }

    if constexpr (std::is_invocable_r_v<void, decltype(fn)>) {
        std::cout << "void function call" << std::endl;
        fn();
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "float function call (never works!)" << std::endl;
        [[maybe_unused]] auto res = fn();
    }
}
 
void f1()
{
}

float f2()
{
    return 0.0f;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Call for function void f1()" << std::endl;
    process(f1);

    std::cout << "Call for function float f2()" << std::endl;
    process(f2);
}

I see per Why doesn't std::is_invocable_r_v<void, TFun> return false if the function does not return void explanation how this happens.
Two questions are still on the table:

Why is it implemented in this way? What is the reason for such a counter-intuitive behaviour?
What is the best workaround in case I can't specify the exact type, like float here? I see some solutions in the comments under the answer in the aforementioned question, but I can't figure out which is most robust and how exactly to apply them safely.


The first question “on the table” is literally the same as the other question (just one more layer of “why?”), and the second sounds like it should be a comment on that answer.

The behavior seems perfectly intuitive to me. I was just about to expain why, but the third comment on the answer you cite expresses my sentiment well. The other two comments show how you can check for "the return type is exactly void" (as opposed to "convertible to void", which any type is).
